# Make an input edit the dates corresponding to the weekdays

Tags: python

[What it Currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogS6G.png)

```
def see_hours_clicked():
    remove_see_hours_widgets()
    print("Button 3 clicked!")
    hours_title.place(x=100, y=15)
    worker_select.config(font=("Arial", 20))
    worker_select.place(x=275, y=13)
    refresh_button.config(command=lambda: refresh(datetime.strptime(date_input.get() if date_input.get() != '' else datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), "%d-%m-%Y")))
    refresh_button.place(x=180, y=400)
    current_date_input.pack(pady=75)

    # create label for each day of the week with the corresponding date
    date_str = date_input.get()
    if date_str == "":
        date = datetime.today()
    else:
        date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d-%m-%Y")

    refresh(date)



def refresh(date):
    current_weekday = date.weekday()

    # Create labels for each day of the week
    for i, day in enumerate(days):
        day_label = tk.Label(main_menu, text=day + ":")
        day_label.config(font=("Arial", 15))
        day_label.place(x=30, y=125 + i * 35)

        # Calculate the date for this day of the week
        delta = i - current_weekday
        date_i = date + timedelta(days=delta)

        # Create a label for the date
        date_label = tk.Label(main_menu, text=date_i.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
        date_label.config(font=("Arial", 15))
        date_label.place(x=150, y=125 + i * 35)
```

This is the shortened code ^.

What I want is to be able to input a new date and  it will display all the weekdays corresponding to that date. For example:

Input:
06-03-2023

Output:
Monday: 06-03-2023
Tuesday: 07-03-2023
etc.

I can provide any clarification and really need help since I've been trying things for hours.

Full Code: https://pastebin.com/ihwLH3e5

I tried getting the date input and then simply refreshing the date and redrawing it on the tkinter screen.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.  **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get all weekdays of the input day?
If i guess right,i write a function doing this,can return all weekdays of this days.
You can modify the fucntion to adapte your progress.
If wrong guess,i hope help give your a little thought
Please try ...
Use Case:

```
inputs:
06-03-2023
output:
['Monday : 06-03-2023', 'Tuesday : 07-03-2023', 'Wednesday : 08-03-2023', 'Thursday : 09-03-2023', 'Friday : 10-03-2023']

inputs:
07-03-2023
output:
['Monday : 06-03-2023', 'Tuesday : 07-03-2023', 'Wednesday : 08-03-2023', 'Thursday : 09-03-2023', 'Friday : 10-03-2023']

inputs:
01-03-2023
output:
['Monday : 27-02-2023', 'Tuesday : 28-02-2023', 'Wednesday : 01-03-2023', 'Thursday : 02-03-2023', 'Friday : 03-03-2023']

inputs:
26-03-2023
output:
['Monday : 20-03-2023', 'Tuesday : 21-03-2023', 'Wednesday : 22-03-2023', 'Thursday : 23-03-2023', 'Friday : 24-03-2023']

inputs:
25-03-2023
output:
['Monday : 20-03-2023', 'Tuesday : 21-03-2023', 'Wednesday : 22-03-2023', 'Thursday : 23-03-2023', 'Friday : 24-03-2023']
```

```
import datetime

WEEK = {0: "Monday",
        1: "Tuesday",
        2: "Wednesday",
        3: "Thursday",
        4: "Friday",
        5: "Saturday",
        6: "Sunday"}


def get_weekday_list(now_date: datetime.datetime) -> list[str]:
    weekdays = []
    now = now_date.weekday()
    weekdays_num = 5
    if now >= weekdays_num:
        now_date = datetime.timedelta(days=weekdays_num - 1 - now) + now_date
        now = weekdays_num - 1

    for i in range(now):
        weekdays.insert(0, datetime.timedelta(days=(-1 * (i + 1))) + now_date)
    for i in range(weekdays_num - now):
        weekdays.append(datetime.timedelta(days=i) + now_date)
    result = []
    for d in weekdays:
        result.append(f"{WEEK.get(d.weekday())} : {d.day:02d}-{d.month:02d}-{d.year}")

    return result


date = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-03-2023", "%d-%m-%Y")
print(get_weekday_list(date))
```